# Transitioning from Excel to R: how to implement if statement and index logic in R?

Tags: r, excel

As the title describes, I am transitioning from Excel to R, but I find that implementing really tricky data manipulation is still more intuitive in Excel rather than R.

I have two data frames:

```
A <- read.table(text="Var1  Var2    Var3    Var4
                      1 0   2   0
                      3 4   0   0
                      0 6   0   7", header=T)
B <- read.table(text="VarA  VarB
                      2.24  1.82
                      3.07  2.97
                      6.5   7.46", header=T)
```

I would like to create a 3rd data frame from A and B that is a follows:

```
Result <- read.table(text="Result1  Result2 Result3 Result4
                           2.24     NA      1.82    NA
                           3.07     2.97    NA      NA
                           NA       6.5     NA      7.46", header=T)
```

So if an element in row `r` and column `c` of data frame `A` <> 0, then in row `r` and column `c` of data frame `Results` place, in sequential order, elements from row `r` of data frame `B`.

In Excel I would use a formula such as:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `matrix` objects are filled by column, not row, you have to do a bit of `t`ransposition to make sure they are filled in the right order:

```
replace(replace(A,TRUE,NA), which(t(A)!=0,arr.ind=TRUE)[,2:1], t(B) )

#     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#[1,] 2.24   NA 1.82   NA
#[2,] 3.07 2.97   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA 6.50   NA 7.46
```

Comment: thank you very much. Is there anything to watch out for when scaling this to larger matrices?

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
r1 <- (NA^!A)*unlist(lapply(B, rep, ncol(A)/ncol(B)))
colnames(r1) <- paste0("Result", 1:ncol(r1))
r1
#     Result1 Result2 Result3 Result4
#[1,]    2.24      NA    1.82      NA
#[2,]    3.07    3.07      NA      NA
#[3,]      NA    6.50      NA    7.46
```

---

Based on the comment

```
 t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(A)), function(i) {
           x1 <- NA^(!A[i,])
           x1[!is.na(x1)] <- B[i,]
          unlist(x1)}))
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,] 2.24   NA 1.82   NA
 #[2,] 3.07 2.97   NA   NA
 #[3,]   NA 6.50   NA 7.46
```

Or a modified code by @shayaa

```
t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(A)), function(i) {
            x1 <- ((A>0)^NA)[i,]
            x1[!is.na(x1)] <- B[i,]
            unlist(x1)}))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, why is emelemt r1[2,2] 3.07 instead of 2.97?

Comment: `t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(A)), function(i) {
      x1 <- ((A>0)^NA)[i,]
      x1[!is.na(x1)] <- B[i,]
      unlist(x1)}))` should be faster and more comprehensible (to me at least)

Comment: Because `A` is already an integer matrix, which is more elevated a data type in the hierarchy than logical. It provides more information. `!A` needs to convert 0 to `FALSE` and then negate that. Plus I find powers of `NA` to be less confusing than bases of `NA`.